# Formatting MySQL query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql

I am posting here after reading many similar threads but that doesn't resolve my problem, so I need MySQL experts to help me identify what's wrong with this query:

The query looks like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.ID), p.*, pm.*, t.*, tt.*, tr.* 
FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta pm, wp_terms as t, wp_term_taxonomy as tt, wp_term_relationships as tr 
'WHERE p.ID = pm.post_id 
AND t.term_id = tt.term_id 
AND tt.taxonomy = wpsc_product_category 
AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
AND tr.object_id = p.ID 
AND p.post_type = wpsc-product 
AND pm.meta_key != _wpsc_price 
AND (p.post_title LIKE '%'\"some string to search\"'%' 
     OR p.post_content LIKE '%'\"some string to search\"'%' 
     OR pm.meta_value = '\"some string to search\"' 
     OR t.name LIKE '%'\"some string to search\"'%') 
GROUP BY p.ID ORDER By p.ID '
```

I don't what's wrong in the query format to get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''WHERE p.ID = pm.post_id AND t.term_id = tt.term_id AND tt.taxonomy = wpsc_produ' at line 1
```

In my query, I need to integrate strings, and it's too late for me to change to PDO. How can I fix that error?

PS: I am running on local server, so php info shows me this information about MySQL server, I guess it's the version:

```
Client API version  5.5.29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, you have an extra single quote before the `WHERE` clause.

As a sidenote, `DISTINCT` keyword will be more likely to be useless because it will only work if all values in all columns are equal on both row otherwise the row is unique even if they have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quote marks around the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should always keep the same convention across your query to make it more readable and less likely to get an error.

This does not affect the outcome but if you use aliases "wp_posts p" OR "wp_posts AS p" are equivalent but you mix in this query. I have made the convention the same for you and fixed your query below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.ID), p.*, pm.*, t.*, tt.*, tr.* 
FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta pm, wp_terms t, wp_term_taxonomy tt, wp_term_relationships tr 
WHERE p.ID = pm.post_id 
AND t.term_id = tt.term_id 
AND tt.taxonomy = wpsc_product_category 
AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
AND tr.object_id = p.ID 
AND p.post_type = wpsc-product 
AND pm.meta_key != _wpsc_price 
AND (p.post_title LIKE "%some string to search%" 
     OR p.post_content LIKE "%some string to search%" 
     OR pm.meta_value = "some string to search" 
     OR t.name LIKE "%some string to search%") 
GROUP BY p.ID ORDER By p.ID
```